# How to save response data to CSV file that i am generating in Simple Data Writer in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am executing one Thread Group which have multiple Http Request. And I am capturing the Error result into a CSV file using Simple Data Writer. But unable to add the response data to the same file. Can you guys please let me know how I can add the response data to this CSV file or is there any other way that we can use for this purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use simple data writer but change the option to produce XML. Remove CSV and select "Save as XML". There is a option to "Save Response Data(XML)" that is what you require as shown below.

Put the result file output format as ".jtl" and open it in the Excel to see the results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to Simple Data Writer for this, it can be done by amending [JMeter Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config):

1. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up
3. Next time when you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   response data for failed samplers will be added to the `results.jtl` file, you will be able to inspect it using either [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) or your favorite text/XML viewer/editor.